# Is possible to make a <div> writable by user?

Tags: javascript, html

have to build a system that when a user write in a box a word that starts with # this is wrapped inside an html element. Inside input-text and textarea html don't work. I had thought with a div, is possible?

Comment: I'm confused about your question.....  Are you trying to type in a text box and then have that text appear inside a div?

Comment: is a system like @ facebook function that parse the word with @ and when you have selected a user print in a different  color the word

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Hello, edit me!</div>
```

Not tested in Opera, works in Firefox 3, Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: @Angelbit: try it using "true" as the value, that will work in IE.

Comment: @Chris: It would work fine in Firefox 3, but after your comment I realized IE wouldn't accept XHTML-style attribute/value pairs.

Comment: huh... i had no idea about this.  :)

Comment: @Tim: I don't think anyone does ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but you can make divs editable like this:

`<div contentEditable="true"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why a input or textarea won't work; you might consider handling the events fired when a user enters data into a textarea or a input to accomplish your goal.  Or you might look into a wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

:)

Seriously, you'll need to parse user input and when your parser engine see a "#" symbol, it just wait for the next [space] (for example as a element id delimiter), create a new DOM Element with this id and after that it must update innerHTML of this element by everytime user entered a symbol.

Comment: yes, have altredy the parser, now need a system like @ facebook that highlighting the #word like FB